# What is the recommended way to structure Sass with Zen theme?

Tags: 7, theming

I have just started using Sass and decided to go ahead and build a theme with Zen for the first time. My very first task is to split the header region into 3 separate regions: header-left, header-main, header-right. From what I've read so far, the best practice to do this is to go in your subtheme's .info file and declare the region and then go to the page.tpl.php file and use the corresponding variables.

I also understand that I will probably have to write Sass that looks like this:

```
.header-container {
 @include zen-grid-container;
}

.header-left {
 @include zen-grid-item(3, 1);
}

.header-main {
 @include zen-grid-item(3, 2);
}

.header-right {
 @include zen-grid-item(3, 3);
}
```

My questions are the following:

1) Where do I add my Sass? Defining the structure of a new region seems like a good fit for the layouts directory. Do I add Sass in the layouts/_responsive.scss file or do I create a new file like layouts/_custom.scss?

2) How do I organize my custom styling in a Zen subtheme? Is there a "best-practices" guide that describes how things should be ordered?

Comment: There is a best practices style guide [SMACSS](https://smacss.com) for structuring CSS, but how you translate it to Zen SASS folder and file structure is up to you. Also look at [Understanding SMACSS file structure for subthemes](https://www.drupal.org/node/2087061) and similar posts.

Comment: These links were really helpful for me to get a better grasp of how my stylesheets can be organized. I think this comment deserves to be incorporated in the accepted answer or at least be an answer of its own for posterity reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I add Sass in the layouts/_responsive.scss file or do I create a new file like layouts/_custom.scss?

Completely up to you. Modularisation is always a good thing, how far you go with implementing that as partials depends on your tastes, and how much code you actually need to write.

> How do I organize my custom styling in a Zen subtheme? Is there a "best-practices" guide that describes how things should be ordered?

I wouldn't have thought so. There isn't an industry standard for structuring a Sass project, so any claims of "best practice" or "this should be done like this" that you see must be taken with a pinch of salt.

It's mostly common sense in my experience. If a file's getting too big, split it up. If natural groups start to form (views, node, users) then you might want to split those up into sub-folders. If you're not already using it, [Sass globbing](https://github.com/chriseppstein/sass-globbing) will take the pain out of including partials if you have a lot of them.